# Funny behaviour from Adobe Flex Transitions (2)

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, transition

No matter what I do, my transitions won't work as expected. I'll explain the issues and then place the code at the bottom.

There are 4 States in my application.

`goButton` is present only in `"State1"` and `"State2"`.

`State1` and `State2` are nearly the same, but the `y` property of the `goButton` is diffrent in each. So I've made a little transition that moves the Button back and forth. Good so far.

However, *both* `"State1"` and `"State2"` can also be Transitioned to `"State3"`. But there's no `goButton` in `"State3"`, so I've used the `<s:Fade>` and the `<s:RemoveAction>` effects to get rid of it.

The Transition from  `"State1"` to `"State3"` works **ok**, but the Transition from `"State2"` to `"State3"` **doesn't**.

When I attempt to call the transition from `"State2"` to `"State3"` the `goButton` flickers/flashes quickly back to the position where it was in `"State1"` and only the the Transition to `"State3"` actually takes place.

this is my `goButton`

`<s:Button id="goButton" includeIn="State1,State2" x="319" y="212" width="33" height="33"
                  click="goButton_clickHandler()"
                  icon="@Embed('file:///C:/Users/Felipe/Downloads/1317358341_magnifier_medium.png')"
                  toolTip="go"
                  x.State2="319" y.State2="275"/>`

and these are the relevant Transitions:

```
<s:Transition fromState="State1" toState="State3" >
            <s:Sequence>
                <s:Fade duration="700" targets="{[searchLabel,searchTextInput,inLabel,inDropDownList,goButton,addNewLessonButton]}" />
                <s:RemoveAction targets="{[searchLabel,searchTextInput,inLabel,inDropDownList,goButton,addNewLessonButton]}" />
                <s:AddAction targets="{[lessonsDataGrid,backButton]}" />
                <s:Fade duration="700" targets="{[lessonsDataGrid,backButton]}" />
            </s:Sequence>
        </s:Transition>

        <s:Transition fromState="State2" toState="State3" >
            <s:Sequence>
                <s:Fade duration="700" targets="{[searchLabel,searchTextInput,inLabel,inDropDownList,tagsLabel,tagsTextInput,goButton,addNewLessonButton]}" />
                <s:RemoveAction targets="{[searchLabel,searchTextInput,inLabel,inDropDownList,tagsLabel,tagsTextInput,goButton,addNewLessonButton]}" />
                <s:AddAction targets="{[lessonsDataGrid,backButton]}" />
                <s:Fade duration="700" targets="{[lessonsDataGrid,backButton]}" />
            </s:Sequence>
        </s:Transition>
```

My guess is that Flex always (don't ask me why) moves the component back to its original position before performing a Transition. **I've tried a different version of this app** in which I set the `x` and `y` properties of my `goButton` to what they are in `"State2"` and then set `x.State1 = something else` and `y.State1 = something else` and guess what happens? I get the exact inverse problem! Transition from `"State2"` to `"State3"` is ok but the Transition from `"State1"` to `"State3"` doesn't work, as the `goButton` flickers back to its original position (now it is the position in `"State2"`) and only then does the Transition takes place.

Man this is driving me crazy.
***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**//***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**
__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_* //***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

**EDIT**

**I've added a link to the app >>>>[HERE](http://queirozf.com/lessonslearnt/lessonslearnt.html)<<<<<<** You can see the issue by selecting the option 'selected tags' and then clicking the 'goButton' . You'll see what I'm talking about. View source is available!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's looking for an x,y for the goButton in State3.  If you don't set one explicitly, it falls back to the default.  Adding

```
x.State3="{this.x}" y.State3="{this.x}"
```

to `<s:Button id="goButton" ... />` fixed it for me.

Comment: It did a first test and it seemed to work. If it turns out to work evertyime you'll be my official hero

Comment: I've been struggling with this one for more than 5 days. How did you figure that out?

Comment: No secret method, I'm afraid.  Just playing around with it awhile.  It was definitely helpful to have a link to the app and source code, without having a wall of code in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're making this too complicated.  Just set includeIn="state1,state3" for the button.  No need for any add action.  Then create one Fade transition that sets the goButton as its target.  The Spark fade is smart enough to figure out how to handle that situation without further help from you.

Check out http://polygeek.com/2304_flex_simple-flex-4-component-checkedunchecked for more details.

Comment: well State3 is precisely the state I don't want the button to be included in.... I know it could be simpler, but it should still work the way it is.

Comment: Well then, set the includeIn state1,state2, and the x.state1 and y.state1, etc.

Comment: I really need the addAction and removeAction... I can't it happen the way I want without it.

Answer (score 0):

**>>>LL<<<<**

OK I think I've singled out this behaviour and do believe it's a **BUG** or **GLITCH**.

I'll see if anyone has anything to add and if nobody shows up I'll file a bug report.

**Steps to reproduce:**

- create a button that's present in two different states, in different x,y coordinates. For example, your button will have a value for x and for y and you'll have to set its position in the other state, something like `x.State2 = something` and `y.State2=something`
- now create a transition from State2 (if State1 is your original State) to a third State called State3.
- the transition should have a `<s:Sequence>` sequence of steps, preferably involving RemoveActions and Fades, like the ones I've used above.